# Django 1.8 makemigrations generates a duplicated migration every time due to validators

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-validation

I have a model which has a field with the following validator:

```
validators=[
        FileValidator(
            allowed_extensions=ALLOWED_PHOTO_EXT,
            allowed_mimetypes=ALLOWED_PHOTO_MIME_TYPES,
            max_size=ALLOWED_PHOTO_MAX_SIZE,
        )
    ],
```

Here goes the validator itself

```
@deconstructible
class FileValidator(object):
    """
    Validator for files, checking the size, extension and mimetype.
    Initialization parameters:
        allowed_extensions: iterable with allowed file extensions
            ie. ('txt', 'doc')
        allowd_mimetypes: iterable with allowed mimetypes
            ie. ('image/png', )
        min_size: minimum number of bytes allowed
            ie. 100
        max_size: maximum number of bytes allowed
            ie. 24*1024*1024 for 24 MB
    Usage example::
        MyModel(models.Model):
            myfile = FileField(validators=FileValidator(max_size=24*1024*1024), ...)

    See https://gist.github.com/jrosebr1/2140738 (improved)
    """

    extension_message = _("Extension '%(extension)s' not allowed. Allowed extensions are: '%(allowed_extensions)s.'")
    mime_message = _("MIME type '%(mimetype)s' is not valid. Allowed types are: %(allowed_mimetypes)s.")
    min_size_message = _('The current file %(size)s, which is too small. The minumum file size is %(allowed_size)s.')
    max_size_message = _('The current file %(size)s, which is too large. The maximum file size is %(allowed_size)s.')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.allowed_extensions = kwargs.pop('allowed_extensions', None)
        self.allowed_mimetypes = kwargs.pop('allowed_mimetypes', None)
        self.min_size = kwargs.pop('min_size', 0)
        self.max_size = kwargs.pop('max_size', DEFAULT_FILE_MAX_SIZE)

    def __call__(self, value):
        """
        Check the extension, content type and file size.
        """

        # Check the extension
        ext = splitext(value.name)[1][1:].lower()
        if self.allowed_extensions and not ext in self.allowed_extensions:
            message = self.extension_message % {
                'extension': ext,
                'allowed_extensions': ', '.join(self.allowed_extensions)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)

        # Check the content type
        # mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(value.name)[0] # XXX Alternative guessing way, unsure
        mimetype = magic.from_buffer(value.read(1024), mime=True)
        if self.allowed_mimetypes and not mimetype in self.allowed_mimetypes:
            message = self.mime_message % {
                'mimetype': mimetype,
                'allowed_mimetypes': ', '.join(self.allowed_mimetypes)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)

        # Check the file size
        filesize = len(value)
        if self.max_size and filesize > self.max_size:
            message = self.max_size_message % {
                'size': filesizeformat(filesize),
                'allowed_size': filesizeformat(self.max_size)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)

        elif filesize < self.min_size:
            message = self.min_size_message % {
                'size': filesizeformat(filesize),
                'allowed_size': filesizeformat(self.min_size)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)
```

Every time I run `./manage.py makemigrations app1`

```
0003_auto_20180521_0325.py:
    - Alter field xxx on yyy
```

It generates a new migration every time, which always does the same thing (alter field)

If I comment out my validator, this behaviour stops and the makemigrations displays a "no change detected" message.

What's wrong? How can I avoid this behaviour?

---

Edit: Following @benjamin's answer, here is the full code, including the fix. (`__eq__` function)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import magic

from os.path import splitext
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat

DEFAULT_FILE_MAX_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024  # 10Mo

# Photo, like profile picture
# Only allow web-friendly extensions/mime types, since they'll be displayed on web pages
# TODO Size is huge, should be optimised
ALLOWED_PHOTO_EXT = [
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png',
]

ALLOWED_PHOTO_MIME_TYPES = [
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/x-png',
]

ALLOWED_PHOTO_MAX_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024  # 10Mo

# Any document
# Allow a wide range of extensions and mime types
# TODO Size is huge, should be optimised
ALLOWED_DOCUMENT_EXT = [
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png',
    'tif',
    'bmp',
    'pdf',
    'doc',
    'dot',
    'docx',
    'dotx',
    'xls',
    'xlt',
    'xla',
    'xlsx',
    'xltx',
    'pptx',
    'potx',
    'ppsx',
]

ALLOWED_DOCUMENT_MIME_TYPES = [
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/x-png',
    'image/tiff',
    'image/bmp',
    'application/pdf',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
    'application/msword',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    'application/zip',  # XXX PPTX can be detected as ZIP for some reasons
]

ALLOWED_DOCUMENT_MAX_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024  # 10Mo

# Any document sent to SMoney, which have their own rules and limitations
# Allow a wide range of extensions and mime types
# TODO Size is huge, should be optimised
ALLOWED_DOCUMENT_SMONEY_EXT = [
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png',
    'tif',
    'bmp',
    'pdf',
]

ALLOWED_DOCUMENT_SMONEY_MIME_TYPES = [
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/x-png',
    'image/tiff',
    'image/bmp',
    'application/pdf',
]

ALLOWED_DOCUMENT_SMONEY_MAX_SIZE = 3 * 1024 * 1024  # 3Mo


@deconstructible
class FileValidator(object):
    """
    Validator for files, checking the size, extension and mimetype.
    Initialization parameters:
        allowed_extensions: iterable with allowed file extensions
            ie. ('txt', 'doc')
        allowd_mimetypes: iterable with allowed mimetypes
            ie. ('image/png', )
        min_size: minimum number of bytes allowed
            ie. 100
        max_size: maximum number of bytes allowed
            ie. 24*1024*1024 for 24 MB
    Usage example::
        MyModel(models.Model):
            myfile = FileField(validators=FileValidator(max_size=24*1024*1024), ...)

    See https://gist.github.com/jrosebr1/2140738 (improved)
    """

    extension_message = _("Extension '%(extension)s' not allowed. Allowed extensions are: '%(allowed_extensions)s.'")
    mime_message = _("MIME type '%(mimetype)s' is not valid. Allowed types are: %(allowed_mimetypes)s.")
    min_size_message = _('The current file %(size)s, which is too small. The minumum file size is %(allowed_size)s.')
    max_size_message = _('The current file %(size)s, which is too large. The maximum file size is %(allowed_size)s.')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.allowed_extensions = kwargs.pop('allowed_extensions', None)
        self.allowed_mimetypes = kwargs.pop('allowed_mimetypes', None)
        self.min_size = kwargs.pop('min_size', 0)
        self.max_size = kwargs.pop('max_size', DEFAULT_FILE_MAX_SIZE)

    def __call__(self, value):
        """
        Check the extension, content type and file size.
        """

        # Check the extension
        ext = splitext(value.name)[1][1:].lower()
        if self.allowed_extensions and not ext in self.allowed_extensions:
            message = self.extension_message % {
                'extension': ext,
                'allowed_extensions': ', '.join(self.allowed_extensions)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)

        # Check the content type
        # mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(value.name)[0] # XXX Alternative guessing way, unsure
        mimetype = magic.from_buffer(value.read(1024), mime=True)
        if self.allowed_mimetypes and not mimetype in self.allowed_mimetypes:
            message = self.mime_message % {
                'mimetype': mimetype,
                'allowed_mimetypes': ', '.join(self.allowed_mimetypes)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)

        # Check the file size
        filesize = len(value)
        if self.max_size and filesize > self.max_size:
            message = self.max_size_message % {
                'size': filesizeformat(filesize),
                'allowed_size': filesizeformat(self.max_size)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)

        elif filesize < self.min_size:
            message = self.min_size_message % {
                'size': filesizeformat(filesize),
                'allowed_size': filesizeformat(self.min_size)
            }

            raise ValidationError(message)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
                isinstance(other, self.__class__) and
                self.allowed_extensions == other.allowed_extensions and
                self.allowed_mimetypes == other.allowed_mimetypes and
                self.min_size == self.min_size and
                self.max_size == self.max_size
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am willing to guess this is because of the lack of an `__eq__` method in the validator class. Something in the default comparisons is looking 'not equal' on two instances initialized in the same way based on its `__dict__`. Try adding an explicit:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (isinstance(other, self.__class__) and 
            self.allowed_extensions == other.allowed_extensions and
            self.allowed_mimetypes == other.allowed_mimetypes and
            self.min_size == self.min_size and
            self.max_size == self.max_size
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/app_name/migrations
```

delete all .py files except **__init__.py**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If this doesn't work, then you can try something I have already done

Inside the view I check if the image is valid like this

```
def check_image(request):

    if len(request.FILES) != 0:

        image = request.FILES['image'] # <input type="file" name="image" ....>
        ext = os.path.splitext(image.name)[1]

        if ext in ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif']:
            # file is image
            x=0
        else:
            # file is not image
            y=0

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I had just done exactly that (which fixed other issues). Also, my issue was in the Model itself, not in the view.

Comment: Okay, I understand now you were providing an alternative solution, to do the check in the view, I don't like it much (I mean, it SHOULD be done in the view regardless), because there are many forms and I may miss some. I'm maintaining a big codebase and prefer to keep it consistent with what was done before, even though your solution would work as well.